# NextJS How to get metadata from an internal path

Tags: node.js, next.js, next.js13

Inside `/pages/api/url` I have the `url` API I am trying to fetch the metadata of an internal path (e.g. `/article/articleID` or `http://localhost:3000/article/articleID`), but every time I try to make the call using `fetch` (I have tried both the standard `fetch` function and the one from the `node-fetch` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

It works very well with external URLs, but when I use an internal one, I get the following error:

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/article/*articleID* failed, reason: socket hang up"
```

My `next.config.js` looks as follows, the `async headers()` section being added specifically to try solving this issue (suggestion got from [this post](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-cors-next-js-handle-cross-origin-requests/)):

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["images.unsplash.com"],
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

How can I make these internal requests so that I can get the metadata from paths that are internal to the app (which are basically scraped from the page using `root.querySelector()`)?